# How to do order in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this query:

```
case_timeline = Case.select('cases.*, case_steps.*, tasks.*, task_statuses.*')
      .joins(case_steps: { tasks: :task_status} )
      .where('cases.id = ?', case_1.id)
      .where('task_statuses.task_status_name in (?)', ['Open', 'Overdue', 'Completed'])
      .order('tasks.end_date DESC')

completed_timeline =
case_timeline
.select{|task| task.task_status_name == "Completed" }
```

How can I order this by date? I tried this:

```
completed_timeline =
case_timeline
.select{|task| task.task_status_name == "Completed" }
.order('end_date')
```

but it's giving the error:

```
undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x000000051da2e0>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the order method on the object called before calling select.

```
completed_timeline =
case_timeline.order('end_date')
.select{|task| task.task_status_name == "Completed" }
```

This is due to the fact that case_timeline returns an ActiveRecord object which knows how to respond to order, where calling select returns an Array object which does not know how to respond to order.

Answer (score 0):

[`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-select) with a block converts the [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) to an [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html); from [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-select):

> You can pass a block so it can be used just like `Array#select`. This builds an array of objects from the database for the scope, converting them into an array and iterating through them using `Array#select`.

Since `task_status_name` appears to be a column, it would be best to do a `where` to avoid converting it to an Array entirely:

```rb
completed_timeline = case_timeline.where(task_status_name: 'Completed')
                                  .order('end_date')
```

Alternatively, move the `select` call to be *after* all [query method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html) calls.